# yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag

Tags: python, yaml, fb-hydra

I have a yaml file which has the following lines:

```
grasp_pose: !!python/object/new:geometry_msgs.msg._Pose.Pose
    state:
      - !!python/object/new:geometry_msgs.msg._Point.Point
        state: [0.445, -0.449, 0.116]
```

which loads with no problem using yaml:

```
with open(os.path.expanduser(config_path), 'r') as f:
    self.config = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)
```

However, using hydra and the `@hydra.main(config_path=config_path, strict=True)` as described [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/intro/), I get the following error:

```
    main()
  File "/xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hydra/main.py", line 24, in decorated_main
    strict=strict,
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 174, in run_hydra
    overrides=args.overrides,
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hydra/_internal/hydra.py", line 79, in run
    config_file=config_file, overrides=overrides, with_log_configuration=True
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hydra/_internal/hydra.py", line 343, in compose_config
    config_file=config_file, overrides=overrides, strict=strict
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hydra/_internal/config_loader.py", line 61, in load_configuration
    job_cfg = self._create_cfg(cfg_filename=config_file, record_load=False)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hydra/_internal/config_loader.py", line 437, in _create_cfg
    cfg = self._load_config_impl(cfg_filename, record_load=record_load)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hydra/_internal/config_loader.py", line 253, in _load_config_impl
    loaded_cfg = OmegaConf.load(fullpath)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/omegaconf/omegaconf.py", line 61, in load
    return OmegaConf.create(yaml.load(f, Loader=get_yaml_loader()))
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 43, in get_single_data
    return self.construct_document(node)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 52, in construct_document
    for dummy in generator:
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 404, in construct_yaml_map
    value = self.construct_mapping(node)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 210, in construct_mapping
    return super().construct_mapping(node, deep=deep)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 135, in construct_mapping
    value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 92, in construct_object
    data = constructor(self, node)
  File "xxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 420, in construct_undefined
    node.start_mark)
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object/new:geometry_msgs.msg._Pose.Pose'
  in "xxxxxxxxx/config/rl_config.yaml", line 85, column 15
```

I'm not sure what the problem is however and lack experience in how yaml works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OmegaConf - the underlying library powering the configuration object in Hydra - does not support arbitrary objects in YAML files.
There is however a feature called Structured Configs in OmegaConf and Hydra 1.0 (which is installable as a release candidate and will be released soon) that adds powerful static typing to your config objects.

I recommend that you go over the [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vT_UIV7hCnquIbLUm4NnkUpXvPEh33IKiUEvPRF850WKA8opOlZOszjKdZ3tPmf8u7hGNP6HpqS-NT5/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.p) or the [docs](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.0_branch/), as well as the [Hydra 1.0 Structured Configs](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/tutorials/structured_config/intro) tutorial.

Comment: is there any estimate regarding when this release might be available?

Comment: Yes. A few hours ago.
https://hydra.cc/blog/2020/09/03/Hydra_1.0

Comment: but how should I modify the config example in the above question (should I actually modify it?)

Comment: You should definitely modify it. How exactly to design your config is not something I can tell you. read the documentation and experiment.

Comment: YAML supports creating actual objects while parsing. OmegaConf and Hydra does not support that. See this to lean how to instantiate objects from the config:
https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/instantiate_objects/overview